# System.MissingMethodException when creating new column based on custom RichImageField field type

Tags: 2010, custom-field-types

I'm trying to create a custom field type inherited from the publishing RichImageField type. I did the following,
1- Created the XML declaration of the column as follows

```
<FieldTypes>
    <FieldType>
        <Field Name="TypeName">PublishingImageWithValidation</Field>
        <Field Name="ParentType">Image</Field>
        <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Publishing Image With Validation</Field>
        <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Publishing image with validation on width, height, and size</Field>
        <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
        <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">
            CustomColumnsAndControls.CustomColumns.PublishingImageWithValidation,
            $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$
        </Field>
    </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

2- Created the following class

```
namespace CustomColumnsAndControls.CustomColumns
{
    class PublishingImageWithValidation : RichImageField
    {
        public PublishingImageWithValidation() : base(){}
    }
}
```

After deploying the above, I'm able to see my new field type in the field types list as shown below

[image]

But when I try to create a new site column based on it, I get an exception, and here is the exception details from the SharePoint logs

> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
>   'CustomColumnsAndControls.CustomColumns.PublishingImageWithValidation' not found.    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateNewFieldInternal(String
>   typeName, String displayName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldNewPage.Save()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldNewPage.BtnOk_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String
>   eventArgu...  bd96166d-7e70-40bb-8d0a-64cbc2071ee8

It says "constructor not found"!. The default constructor is there in my class and it's referring the base. I didn't find any other constructors in the parent type to refer to.

What could be the problem?

Comment: ... Seems you where right Mohammed. My test was wrong, I had reflected over the wrong constructor... so the sample I had posted was wrong. I have removed it to avoid noise. Anyway, I will have a look at that blog and see if i can understand something more. Again, sorry for the error... wrong activator method opened in reflector